# Azure function Cannot locate the method signature with the given input

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I create a function to trigger when blob storage is being create or update.
My blob structure : **container/a-123/b-123/c-1-2-3**

while 123 is a dynamic value

And here my function

```
public class BlobTriggerFunction {
/**
 * This function will be invoked when a new or updated blob is detected at the specified path. The blob contents are provided as input to this function.
 */
@FunctionName("blobtriggerfunction")
@StorageAccount("connection")
public static void run(
        @BlobTrigger(name = "container", path = "container") CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob,
        @BindingName("name") String name,
        final ExecutionContext context
) {
    context.getLogger().info(cloudBlockBlob.getUri().toString());
    context.getLogger().info(name);
}
```

}

And I always get the error

> Executing 'Functions.blobtriggerfunction' (Reason='New blob detected: container/u-123/c-123/m-1-2-3-a50a-025592397574', Id=6b9ae40c-f92b-46d4-8c1-41791167c355)
>    Cannot locate the method signature with the given input
>    System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.blobtriggerfunction. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
>    Exception: Cannot locate the method signature with the given input
>    Stack: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Cannot locate the method signature with the given input
>       at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.lambda$execute$0(JavaMethodExecutor.java:49)
>       at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.execute(JavaMethodExecutor.java:49)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:47)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:91)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

What wrong with my method signature, I go stuck on this.
I am really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Is this `cloudBlockBlob.getUri()` necessary for your further development or you just want to output it for test?

Comment: It doesn't really need

Answer (score 3):

Data type `CloudBlockBlob` is not supported in java blob trigger. For this reason, you can't get blob url unless you use azure storage sdk inside your function.

We can use `String`, `byte[]`, POJO class for java blobtrigger content binding. See the [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java#data-types).

For example

```
@BlobTrigger(name = "content", path = "container/{name}", dataType="Binary") byte[] content
```

Note that if you want to use blob name, you should append path with `/{name}`, or you will get the same error.

And I recommend you to keep value of annotation parameter `name` identical to incoming blob name(As I have set both of them to `content`). It's not necessary to make function work, but for better understanding.

Comment: @SophonMen Have updated with more details, you could accept it as an answer for others to refer.

Comment: Yes but what if my blob is huge? I don't want to get it as String or byte[] already fully loaded in memory, I just need a stream only. Is there a way that I just get a notification by means of the trigger, so that I can then use the Storage API to handle the blob as I need? Maybe I can put @BlobTrigger annotation on some more harmless type?

Comment: @PavelS. Can't agree more. But the feature you request is only available in c# function and I haven't found any alternative. Have opened an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/138).

Comment: @JerryLiu I see. Thank you!